# Synonym for "marketing" that doesn't imply selling or profit

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a word that is similar to "marketing" that doesn't imply the idea of commercialization or profit?

For example, a non-profit that assists domestic abuse victims may run a campaign where they advertise their services. They may put up posters, buy billboard space, and so forth. While this *is* marketing, people in that industry may be very reluctant to call it a "marketing campaign". This is because *marketing* tends to carry the connotation of trying to sell something.

Is there a more neutral word?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Consider [***Publicity***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/publicity),

> Material or information used for advertising or promotional purposes

**Usage:**

> The ***publicity*** materials on domestic violence were distributed by members of the NGO.

or ***[Promotion](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/promotion)***

> The publicizing of a product, organization, or venture so as to increase sales or *public awareness*

**Usage:**

> The ***promotional*** events by the non-profit group to increase  awareness on domestic violence

[ODO]

Comment: @Rathony While publicity and promotion are common in the commercial sphere, they don't have the intrinsic commercial connotation of "market."

Comment: @Rathony Failing to deliver a non-profit purpose isn't the same as delivering a for-profit purpose.  Promotion and publicity are neutral in that respect.  The question doesn't actually ask for a term that denotes a non-profit purpose; it asks for a term that doesn't imply a for-profit purpose ("... that doesn't imply the idea of commercialization or profit?").

Comment: @Rathony I disagree with your assertion that these words connote selling for profit. Publicity is just advertising, and everyone knows advertising can be used for all kinds of purposes, not just commercial. Similarly, _promotion_ is often used for non-commercial endeavours. Governments run advertising campaigns to promote a healthy lifestyle. Charities run campaigns to promote awareness of diseases and to raise funds. The list goes on and on.

Comment: +1, these are good, but marketing is fine too, really. You market yourself in social circles and job interviews. Doesn't mean you're selling yourself for profit.

Comment: In job interviews, you are selling your workforce, so yes, it is about selling.

Comment: *Promotion* very strongly connotes for-profit advertising

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede - Consider "NGO campaign for Mental Health Promotion" / "Government promoting Cleanliness in Rural Towns" / "Promotion of Organic Food as opposed to Biologically Tampered ones" and so on....
It depends on how and when the word "Promotion" is used. It need not always mean "for-profit" activities/ads.

Answer (score 17):

You might consider using the word **outreach**, as it is essentially what marketing is called when you're talking about NGOs who are attempting to raise awareness of their services among affected communities.

> Outreach - an ​effort to ​bring ​services or ​information to ​people
>   where they ​live or ​spend ​time:
>
> E.g. The ​centre was ​awarded a ​grant for outreach to the ​homeless.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outreach):

> Outreach is an activity of providing services to any populations who
>   might not otherwise have access to those services. A key
>   component of outreach is that the groups providing it are not
>   stationary, but mobile; in other words they are meeting those in need
>   of outreach services at the locations where those in need
>   are. In addition to delivering services, outreach has an
>   educational role, raising the awareness of existing services.
>
> Outreach is often meant to fill in the gap in the services provided by
>   mainstream (often, governmental) services, and is often carried out by
>   non-profit, non-Governmental organizations.

Answer (score 10):

**Raising Awareness**

As an expression it is a bit like publicity but without the PR (Public Relations) undertone.  Whilst I like the word propaganda, it too has political and other  connotations to political and unpleasant

Answer (score 7):

**Messaging** is something of an insider's term. See linked document.

http://nonprofitanswerguide.org/faq/marketing-communications/how-are-key-messages-developed/

Comment: I like the general sentiment here, although the fact that the linked website placed that page in the "Marketing & Communications" section suggestions that it might be a niche term that isn't widely used.

Comment: I can confirm that this word is widely used and understood in activist/advocacy contexts.

Answer (score 5):

From the question:

> "For example, a non-profit that assists domestic abuse victims may run a **campaign** where they **advertise** their services"

Have you considered calling this an **advertising campaign**?

Comment: To me this seems the obvious answer.  Trump, Clinton, and friends are not busy selling merchandise.  They are trying to convince you to vote for them.

Answer (score 2):

[Propaganda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propaganda) fits both for the idea spreading, and the "services" to accomplish the goal from the interested party / NPO.

In spanish, marketing students have a strict distinction when they say *marketing* and *propaganda*: When you promote something related to sell a product, you are related to the term *marketing*, but when the idea is about social impact, behavior, politics, ... the term they use is *propaganda*, even when the emotional and memethics aspects are almost the same, but they say: *you try to sell something? no? then it is propaganda*.

Comment: I think this term has too negative a connotation when used in English to be appropriate for the OP's example, but +1 for an interesting contribution.

Comment: Yep. In the day-to-day this sounds with negative connotation. I forgot that since where I live (i.e. not USA) that term is rarely used, so perhaps it has a negative connotation but it has not so big impact here. However, in theoretical/academical environments, this one is *the* word for the phenomenom.

Answer (score 2):

The question is sometimes asked, as Dan Empfield does in the linked article for Slowtwitch[dot]com, whether actions and positions taken are done so for the purpose of “[advocacy or {for the purpose of} marketing](http://www.slowtwitch.com/Bike_Fit/General_Fit_Articles/Bike_fit_systems_marketing_or_advocacy__881.html),” and after reading the eight steps listed in a ‘Yahoo Answer’ as necessary for implementing a [successful] “[advocacy campaign](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20101121225305AAxUWBh), I find myself asking whether these steps differ greatly from the six listed as required for a successful “[marketing campaign](http://under30ceo.com/6-steps-for-a-successful-marketing-campaign/)” on the link to ‘under30ceo[dot]com’.

In light of the overlap of “advocacy” and “marketing” and to the extent that true **advocacy** and **advocacy campaigns** are driven by something other than commercializing and selling things for [immediate] profit, I think you could consider using those terms in place of “marketing” and “marketing campaigns.”

Answer (score 1):

***Evangelism*** may be a suitable candidate.

**evangelist**

1  A person who seeks to convert others to the Christian faith, especially by public preaching.

1.1 A layperson engaged in Christian missionary work.

**1.2 A zealous advocate of something**

***'he is an evangelist of junk bonds'***

*Source: [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/evangelist)*

For instance, Microsoft has a position called ["Microsoft Technical Evangelist"](https://www.glassdoor.com/Salary/Microsoft-Technical-Evangelist-Salaries-E1651_D_KO10,30.htm). According to Wikipedia, the term tech evangelist started [with a member of the Macintosh team.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technology_evangelist#History_of_term)

Comment: Interesting, but I don't feel it is appropriate for the OP's scenario. Evangelism is a tongue-in-cheek term which implies something of a "holier than thou" attitude, something which is definitely a no-no in any serious, uh, marketing (where I mean "serious" as in "non-humorous" more than "strictly professional"). Also, I have a feeling that this might not be properly understood outside of tech.

Answer (score 0):

**Branding** - the promoting of a product or service by identifying it with a particular brand
http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/branding

From your example, a non-profit assisting domestic abuse victims will assuredly not be selling anything in their campaign, but they will be creating the connection between the issue (domestic abuse) and their identity (ngo's mission). Essentially:

"Branding should both precede and underlie any marketing effort. Branding is not push, but pull. Branding is the expression of the essential truth or value of an organization, product, or service. It is communication of characteristics, values, and attributes that clarify what this particular brand is and is not."
http://www.tronviggroup.com/the-difference-between-marketing-and-branding/

Answer (score 0):

The term "marketing" does have a commercial tone about it. If you are looking for a more neutral term, I would suggest the following:

"Educational"

I also agree with "Awareness" as well as "Outreach", as mentioned by previous posters. Both are great alternatives.

From your example, it seems as though the group is trying to educate the public about their options. That it why I thought a "Campaign to Educate", seemed appropriate. But it does not seem to roll off the tongue as naturally as the two that I said are great alternatives.